# How to escape Hyphen in jquery in Ansible

Tags: jquery, ansible

I'm having trouble with a jquery statement in Ansible. My host name has "-" in its name which I need to specify to bring back the results I need. I have tried various ways to escape the "-" but with no joy. As it stands below is my current task:

```
- name: Query with hyphen
     debug:
      msg: "{{ results.json.list | json_query(querystr) }}"
     vars:
        querystr: "[?hostname=={{ host }}].{hostname: hostname, status: status}"
        host: '["server-bbbv-14"]'
```

I get no error but this is the result I receive:

```
"msg": []
```

Here is my json result I'm querying:

```
"json": {
    "list": [
            {
                "status": "1",
                "hostname": "server-bbbv-10"
            },
            {
                "status": "3",
                "hostname": "server-bbbv-14"
            },
            {
                "status": "3",
                "hostname": "server-bbbv-17"
            },
            {
                "status": "1",
                "hostname": "server-bbbv-11"
            }
      [
}
```

I have also tried '"server-bbbv-14"' which give me the same output.

I tried "server-bbbv-14" and 'server-bbbv-14' and got below error:

```
"msg": "Error in jmespath.search in json_query filter plugin:\ninvalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'"
```

I tried ['server-bbbv-14'] and recevied:

```
"msg": "Error in jmespath.search in json_query filter plugin:\n'literal'"
```

For sanity I tried searching on the status and it works as expected bringing back results that match the given status I put in.

Please note, the vars of host is actually going to be the built in Ansible variable inventory_hostname but as that did not work I have tried setting this manually to get it working first.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to escape hyphens. Your jmespath query is incorrect. Moreover, using jmespath here is not really the best option. In a nutshell, the following `playbook.yml` meets your expectations:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    results:
      json:
        list:
          - status: "1"
            hostname: "server-bbbv-10"
          - status: "3"
            hostname: "server-bbbv-14"
          - status: "3"
            hostname: "server-bbbv-17"
          - status: "1"
            hostname: "server-bbbv-11"

    search_hostname: "server-bbbv-14"

  tasks:

    - name: Get the result with json_query
      vars:
        # Warning: single quotes matter here, see jmespath spec
        # https://jmespath.org/specification.html#raw-string-literals
        query_string: "[?hostname=='{{ search_hostname }}']"
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "{{ results.json.list | json_query(query_string) }}"

    - name: Alternative syntax for json_query raw string
      vars:
        query_string: "[?hostname==`{{ search_hostname }}`]"
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "{{ results.json.list | json_query(query_string) }}"

    - name: Get the same result with stock ansible filters
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "{{ results.json.list | selectattr('hostname', '==', search_hostname) }}"
```

Running that playbook with the task profiler shows both method return the same result and that using the stock filters in this specific case is twice as fast on my machine

```
$ ANSIBLE_CALLBACKS_ENABLED=profile_tasks ansible-playbook playbook.yml 

PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [Get the result with json_query] ******************************************
Friday 25 August 2023  12:38:27 +0200 (0:00:00.010)       0:00:00.010 ********* 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "hostname": "server-bbbv-14",
            "status": "3"
        }
    ]
}

TASK [Alternative syntax for json_query raw string] ****************************
Friday 25 August 2023  12:38:27 +0200 (0:00:00.056)       0:00:00.066 ********* 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "hostname": "server-bbbv-14",
            "status": "3"
        }
    ]
}

TASK [Get the same result with stock ansible filters] **************************
Friday 25 August 2023  12:38:27 +0200 (0:00:00.055)       0:00:00.122 ********* 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "hostname": "server-bbbv-14",
            "status": "3"
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   

Friday 25 August 2023  12:38:27 +0200 (0:00:00.034)       0:00:00.156 ********* 
=============================================================================== 
Get the result with json_query ------------------------------------------ 0.06s
Alternative syntax for json_query raw string ---------------------------- 0.06s
Get the same result with stock ansible filters -------------------------- 0.03s
```

Comment: I tried with stock filter as in your example but received the following, the environment I'm in is on Ansible version 2.8.0 if that makes a difference?: "msg": "<generator object _select_or_reject at 0x7f289ddf3730>"

Comment: Yes it makes a huge difference as ansilble 2.8 is EOL for over 3 years. You should upgrade to something decently up-to-date, i.e. ansible-core 2.15. Since the only official supported installation method is pip nowadays, it's quite easy to install whatever version in // (in a vritualenv if needed). Alternatively, you can add the `| list` filter after `selectattr` to fix that problem in your version.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm restricted with upgrading at present. Adding | list I get this error: "Make sure your variable name does not contain invalid characters like '-': unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'AnsibleUndefined' and 'AnsibleUndefined'"

Comment: You must have typed something wrong => `msg: "{{ results.json.list | selectattr('hostname', '==', search_hostname) | list }}"`. Tested just now in ansible 2.8 running inside python 2.7.18 in a virtualenv

Comment: "Get the result with json_query" when I run this I get "msg": "", although the alternative one works thanks.

Comment: Please refrain from reporting problems before you have thoroughly verified on your side because every task above (provided you added `| list` in the last one) [are working as expected in ansible 2.8](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/1561e1ad688e361c5c0532ac3ca35f5e)

Answer (score 0):

Below is the correct query

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ results.json.list | json_query(querystr) }}"
      vars:
        host: server-bbbv-14
        querystr: '[?hostname==`{{ host }}`].{hostname: hostname, status: status}'
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
  - hostname: server-bbbv-14
    status: '3'
```

---

Note: It's not necessary to use *json_query*. You can use *selectattr* instead. The below expression gives the same result

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ results.json.list | selectattr('hostname', '==', host) }}"
      vars:
        host: server-bbbv-14
```

---

A simpler solution would be to create a dictionary first

```yaml
  hostname_status: "{{ results.json.list|
                       items2dict(key_name='hostname', value_name='status') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  hostname_status:
    server-bbbv-10: '1'
    server-bbbv-11: '1'
    server-bbbv-14: '3'
    server-bbbv-17: '3'
```

This makes the above query trivial.

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    results:
      json:
        list:
          - {hostname: server-bbbv-10, status: '1'}
          - {hostname: server-bbbv-14, status: '3'}
          - {hostname: server-bbbv-17, status: '3'}
          - {hostname: server-bbbv-11, status: '1'}

    hostname_status: "{{ results.json.list|
                         items2dict(key_name='hostname', value_name='status') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ results.json.list | json_query(querystr) }}"
      vars:
        host: server-bbbv-14
        querystr: '[?hostname==`{{ host }}`].{hostname: hostname, status: status}'

    - debug:
        var: hostname_status
```

Comment: creating the dictionary list first seems interesting although this is not filtering or am I missing something?